# Mysql cannot export database

Tags: phpmyadmin

i am trying to export my moodle database on phpmyadmin but whenever i try to export it send me  this error message:

```
Notice in ./libraries/classes/Controllers/ExportController.php#263
Undefined index: output_format

Backtrace

Routing.php#187: PhpMyAdmin\Controllers\ExportController->index(array)
index.php#18: PhpMyAdmin\Routing::callControllerForRoute(
string '/export',
,
,
)
```

even when io click to ignore all it does nothing, what can i do?

and when i refresh the page it shows this error message:

```
index.php: missing parameter: what

index.php: missing parameter: export_type
```

Comment: If you don't have any luck with phpmyadmin - can you use a terminal? `mysqldump -uusername -p databasename > databasename.sql`

Comment: i will try it, i'm using cyberpanel but whenever i try to use terminal it says connection error failed to connecting to backend.

Comment: I have the same issue with php8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded the version on my Xampp to version 7. And it worked.

There are no current solution to this problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think phpMyAdmin isn't ready yet for PHP 8?